# AliExpress Dropshipper API: empty response

Tags: aliexpress

I'm researching AliExpress Dropshipper API. And I've stuck at the very beginning. Here is what I did:

1. Created AliExpress Dropshipper API App and get it approved.
2. Downloaded .NET Core SDK by following this instruction: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=108108&docType=1
3. Successfully obtained access token by following this instruction: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=108969&docType=1
4. Compiled SDK and wrote a simple example - obtaining product info by product ID:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ITopClient client = new DefaultTopClient("http://gw.api.taobao.com/router/rest", *appKey*, *appSecret*);
    AliexpressOfferDsProductSimplequeryRequest req = new AliexpressOfferDsProductSimplequeryRequest();
    req.ProductId = *productId*;
    req.LocalCountry = "US";
    req.LocalLanguage = "en";
    AliexpressOfferDsProductSimplequeryResponse rsp = client.Execute(req, *accessToken*);
    Console.WriteLine(rsp.Body);
}
```

However making a request in the example above, I'm getting an empty response. It looks like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<aliexpress_offer_ds_product_simplequery_response>
    <request_id>15ryoc4ucxgtt</request_id>
</aliexpress_offer_ds_product_simplequery_response>
<!--top033079137236.center.na610-->
```

However the response should be much bigger. Take a look on the "Response Example" section: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=40657&docType=2

1. I've tried different endpoint URLs: gw.api.taobao.com, api.taobao.com, eco.taobao.com - the result is the same.
2. I've tried to use wrong access token to make sure that I get authorization error, and I got it. And I'm not getting it with the correct access token. Which means my access token is fine.
3. I've re-generated SDK to make sure that I'm using the latest version.
4. I've tried different product IDs including those I found in documentation examples as well as I get directly from AliExpress website. For example: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001699302548.html - this item. Product ID is 1005001699302548.

So, what am I doing wrong? What else can I try?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: How did you get the api key? I'm trying to register but it doesn't allow people from the US.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. I'm just writing you to let you know that I'm having a lot of trouble with the sdk as well. I use python but the code seems similar. I've been battling this for about a month. I integrated another api in my web application in like 5 lines of code. This one just seems hard. If I make a breakthrough though, I will let you know.

Best of luck

Comment: Answers are meant to give indications about solving the problem.

Comment: Thank you friend for letting me know that I'm not alone :) Let's keep in touch on this page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they simply have not updated many (if any) docs since moving to the new API.  The new endpoint I believe is at https://api-sg.aliexpress.com/